# WCF Json GET Service: Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree

Tags: json, wcf, get, endpoint

I've been working in .NET for a while now, but I'm new to WCF. I'm trying to create my very first WCF service using JSON. I thought I would start really, really simple and then build from there.  But I have somehow managed to screw up even the most simple of services. Here's what I've got so far.

Web.Config:

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="MarathonInfo.MarathonInfoService">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:10298/MarathonInfoService.svc" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MarathonInfo.IMarathonInfo" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Then, in the service file:

```
namespace MarathonInfo
{
    public class MarathonInfoService : IMarathonInfo
    {
        public String GetData()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
    }
}
```

And in the interface:

```
namespace MarathonInfo
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IMarathonInfo
    {

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/GetData", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        String GetData();
    }
}
```

So, when I go to this url:

```
http://localhost:10298/MarathonInfoService.svc/GetData
```

I get this error:

> The message with To
>   'http://localhost:10298/MarathonInfoService.svc/GetData' cannot be
>   processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the
>   EndpointDispatcher.  Check that the sender and receiver's
>   EndpointAddresses agree.

I am able to execute the service just fine through Visual Studio in debug mode. But in the browser, I only get that error.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Casey

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to create a WCF WebHTTP Endpoint (i.e., one which returns JSON, and uses the [WebGet] / [WebInvoke] attributes), the endpoint needs to have the `<webHttp/>` behavior associated with it.

```
<system.serviceModel> 
  <services> 
    <service name="MarathonInfo.MarathonInfoService"> 
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:10298/MarathonInfoService.svc"
                binding="webHttpBinding"
                contract="MarathonInfo.IMarathonInfo"
                behaviorConfiguration="Web"/> 
    </service> 
  </services> 
  <behaviors> 
    <serviceBehaviors> 
      <behavior> 
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/> 
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/> 
      </behavior> 
    </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="Web">
        <webHttp/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors> 
  <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" /> 
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: I am also having same issue. I have WCF Rest Service project and also Windows Host project. Where I need to give above?